# select people who register the same course but dont know anyone

Tags: mysql, database

Im having trouble find people from the same course I have 3 tables, `people(id, name)`, `knows(id,personA_id,personB_id)`, `course(id,person_id,course_id)` in knows table, person A knows person B if there is something in the row on `personB_id`.

So I was thinking:

```
SELECT p.name FROM people p,knows k
WHERE p.id = k.personA_id 
    AND p.id NOT IN(select k.personB_id from knows)
```

This would return me something that's relevant but I'm missing in the same classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this

```
SELECT p.name from people p
INNER JOIN course c ON p.id = c.person_id
LEFT JOIN knows k ON p.id = k.personA_id
WHERE k.personB_id IS NULL
```

and if you have a course id (ex 4)
you can add

```
AND c.id = 4
```